# Does Mac OS X SNMP report cached memory?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, nagios, snmp

We're using a Nagios plugin to check the chassis of hosts over SNMP. I'm trying to set up a mac os x machine, but it's failing. All the rest of our hosts we're checking are Linux. This is the first Mac.

Investigation shows that I'm trying to get the cached memory. I'm getting this output when I try on the command line.

```
# snmpwalk -v 1 -c public macmachine .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0
Timeout: No Response from macmachine
```

Does Mac OS X's built in SNMPd tell the cached memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly. It only provides via SNMP Memory Buffers, Real Memory, and Swap Space (hrStorageOther, hrStorageRam, and hrStorageVirtualMemory respectively) - you may find this [cacti forum post](http://forums.cacti.net/post-152738.html#152738) helpful in making a script to grab that information however.

However if you're getting at time out instead of:

> `memCached.0 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

you may want to check your SNMP settings on the Mac (`/usr/share/snmp/snmpd.conf` or use `snmpconf`)